# callback de um servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Galera,
Estou envolvido em um projeto que requer o uso da API da Fitbit. No meu código, eu redireciono o usuário ao site da FITBIT para ele autorizar o uso dos dados. Depois de autorizar, eu preciso pegar a URL para conseguir o código Oauth. Como eu faço uma função callback desse redirecionamento? Não é propriamente um ajax request porque não uso nem get nem post nem put, apenas redireciono o usuário.

Comment: Pode nos mostrar o que esteve tentando?

Comment: Normalmente você define uma URL para retorno (callback), essa URL é uma do teu sistema onde tu consegue pegar os dados retornados pelo FITBIT.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se o Fitbit usa Oauth2, mas se for o caso funciona da seguinte forma:

Passo 1:
Vc redireciona o usuário para a página de autenticação passando o id e callback URL via método GET

Passo 2:
Fitbit chama a URL q vc passou passando um código via método GET

Passo 3:
Você pega o código q vc recebeu e o api secret e resubmete para o Fitbit via método POST.

Nesse ponto, o Fitbit vai te retornar um JSON com o access_token, que é o que vc vai utilizar para cada chamada de API.

IMPORTANTE
O seu servidor deve estar acessível na internet, se vc estiver usando o servidor. A sua rede privada ou numa máquina virtual, vc deve configurar o roteador/firewall para liberar acesso externo a porta 80 e 443.

Boa sorte

Comment: Eu entendi,mas o request não necessariamente manda o usuário para o link. Como fazer com que redirecione?É só colocar um window.location dentro do request,na parte do. Done?

Comment: Ou vc pode retornar o http status 302 e adicionar o campo "Location: www.fitbit.etc" no header HTTP, q teria o mesmo efeito. Em suma, o processo é como descrito acima, a forma como vc redireciona depende da tecnologia q vc está usando. O Fitbit usa Oauth2. https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/